# Nested jointable joincolumns in symfony 2 with doctrine 2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

So given the entity Comment, what is the cleanest way to get the CommentPerson to find out if the CommentPerson `isModerator()`?

Without getting your fingers dirty using a repository.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyApp\MyBundle\Repository\CommentRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="comment")
 */
class Comment
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $user_id; //id of entity User

      /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    protected $user; //a user can have many comments


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $commentText;

}


/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyApp\MyBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User //this is the web user
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $person_id; //id of entity Person

      /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    protected $person; //many web users can map to one actual person


    public function getPerson()
    {
        return $this->person;
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyApp\MyBundle\Repository\PersonRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="person")
 */
class Person
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CommentPerson", mappedBy="person")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="person_id")
     */
    private $commentPersons; //one person can have many commentPersons (since one person can be part in many different comment sections, not shown in code here, but take it as a fact)

}


/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyApp\MyBundle\Repository\CommentPersonRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="comment_Person")
 */
class CommentPerson
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $person_id; //this is the id of the entity Person

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    protected $isModerator;

}
```

Comment: Is a Comment created by a CommentPerson? If so, it seems the Comment entity should be linked to CommentPerson instead of (or in addition to) User

Comment: Moderator should be a role, such as Admin or Super Admin. So how do you want to do this, you save roles in several entities. This can make trouble later. Watch you at the FOSUserBundle. This can be a good start. For the control, whether just a moderator wants access to comment, write a Voter (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html).